# Where can I get BibTeX styles for the Belgian BIN Rules?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies

My question is completely described in the title of this topic.

Maybe a short explanation of what the BIN Rules are: it's a complete guideline on how to do the typesetting of various sorts: formal letters, dissertations, reports and so on. It's used in Belgium, and it can be compared with the APA rules, by example.

Where can I find a good BibTeX style that follows the Belgian BIN Rules?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! It will probably be easier to do that with `biblatex`, starting from a biblatex style close to what you want, say `biblatex-apa`, and patching it.

Comment: You've tagged this both `bibtex` and `biblatex` but they use completely different style definitions. If nothing exists, `biblatex` would be easier. But it matters which you mean you need.

Comment: I don't mind about which one I have to use. Nothing exists yet, and for me, the look is more important than the packages used. Where can I get some textual examples of the different BibLaTeX styles? (I need textual examples, because I am a blind student.)

Comment: Can you give us a link to the actual norm? I found http://www.kamaaseik.be/index%20bestanden/studiewijzer/onderzoekscompetenties/bin%20normen.pdf which states in section 4 'Wat nu volgt zijn algemene richtlijnen die kunnen w
orden toegepast. Het is evenwel 
mogelijk dat in sommige vakgebieden [...]  andere [...] regels 
dienen te worden toegepast. Kijk dus eerst na of u geen andere regels moet toepassen.' makes me think that the norm is not really clear.

Comment: Yes, but it is a Dutch version. I can translate it, if needed... This is the link to it: https://jordydeweer.stackstorage.com/s/eXTstE71fFiXHiY

Comment: OK, I guess then that the BIN norm works more or less like ISO/DIN norms for bibliographies: The actual norm is quite liberal in what it really requires, but then all kinds of people slap on their favourite style and call it 'BIN'. Most of that is fairly easy. Do you really have to have underlines, though?

Comment: or it can be italic... It has to be something else than the other text...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This follows the document you uploaded. A few other guides I found on the web had different guidelines and also posed as 'BIN norm'. Note that your guide has inconsistencies between text and example. Furthermore you are missing many important entry types.

This is a start

```
\documentclass[dutch]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authortitle, giveninits=true, uniquename=init]{biblatex} % this is important
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{daras,
  author    = {Daras, K. and Dhaenens, J. J.},
  title     = {Rapporteren: een levenswerk},
  edition   = {3},
  publisher = {Uitgeverij Jozefa},
  location  = {Brugge},
  date      = {2010},
  pagetotal = {513}, 
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

%% the code from here on is important
%% BIN style - START
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim}
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}


\renewbibmacro*{title}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{title}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{subtitle}}
  }
    {}
    {\printtext[title]{%
       \printfield[titlecase]{title}%
       \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
       \printfield[titlecase]{subtitle}}%
     \newunit}%
  \printfield{titleaddon}
  \printunit{\addperiod\space}}

\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}
    {}
    {\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}


\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addcomma\space}}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \newunit}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{\bibstring{jourvol}~#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{\bibstring{number}~#1}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}

\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
  \printfield{issue}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\newbibmacro*{puborginst+location+date}[1]{%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{\usebibmacro{puborginst+location+date}{publisher}}
\renewbibmacro*{institution+location+date}{\usebibmacro{puborginst+location+date}{institution}}
\renewbibmacro*{organization+location+date}{\usebibmacro{puborginst+location+date}{organization}}

%% ... BIN style END ...


\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,daras}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]

Comment: "But i need BIN exactly." Almost seems like a practical joke. :-)

Comment: I don't understand the example code... I am new to LaTeX and I can't understand what you wrote. And it doesn't matter, if it looks like the NBN norm, for me it's all right. Can I also solve this with an extern PDF file, created in Word? so the code is then: \chapter{bibliography} `\inlucdepdf{bibliography}' (when I added the package 'pdfpages')?

Comment: @JordyDeweer The code changes some of the standard macros of `biblatex` to achieve what you want as output. Have a look at [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864) for starters on the subject. Most macros have 'speaking names' and are responsible for what they say they are. If you only include a PDF file from word that has the references in it, LaTeX does not know about it and cannot generate the bibliography for you. In that case, you can't use `biblatex` to typeset your bibliography.

Comment: @Moewe Okay, I'll take a look there and thank you for the explanation. But, if I include a PDF, it also looks good? (It would be nicer when I use bibLaTeX, but if it's the fastest way, I can do so?)

Comment: @JordyDeweer I'm not entirely sure what you mean with the included PDF. If your bibliography was created in Word (or any other program) and is only included as a PDF via `\inlucdepdf` you cannot use `biblatex` to change its appearance. The appearance is already fixed in the PDF. You will have to use BibTeX/`biblatex` way to obtain a bibliography with `.bib` files. Have a look at https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management

Comment: @moewe Can I include the part of the code that changes the macros in an appart file??

Comment: @JordyDeweer You can use `\input` to include a `.tex` file to your preamble. You could then move the code from the preamble to an external file. (I would not do that, but if you insist.) See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/296732/35864

Comment: \moewe But is there a method to create a biblatex style with this, so I don't need to understand everything in de code? (Because I don't do now...)

Comment: @JordyDeweer You don't have to create a new style in a separate file for that. It is simply enough to have the code in your preamble. (No matter whether you really understand it or not.) I have edited the answer to show exactly what is relevant. You need the `\usepackage` line marked with `% this is important`. As well as the block between `%% BIN style - START` and `%% ... BIN style END ...`.

Comment: @moewe Thanks. And what does the filecontents environment do? Do I need this code to let the important code work well, or are the contents of the .bib file enough?
That about input command, is that just a personal thing, why you don't recommend to use it, or does it have a software or other technical reason?

Comment: @JordyDeweer The `filecontents` environment is just here to make the example self-contained - it includes the `.bib` file. You will not need that in a normal document, where you will just have a `.bib` file. There is no technical thing against `\input` (don't use `\include` though! - see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/246/35864)). It's just my personal preference - I don't use `\input` - but then I have never had so long a modification to `biblatex` in my preamble.