# Accessing and changing biblatex.cfg in Overleaf

Tags: biblatex, overleaf

I use Overleaf to write LaTeX-documents, but my department requires a very specific bibliography style. According to [this guide](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/guidelines-for-customizing-biblatex-styles) I need to temper with `biblatex.cfg` and `bibltex.def`. Where can I find and change them in Overleaf, if at all? And what would be a good alternative? (Learning to use LaTeX on my computer isn't really an option due to due dates).

For reference: [the guidelines](https://musikwissenschaft.univie.ac.at/fileadmin/user_upload/i_musikwissenschaft/Studium/RichtlinienSchriftlicheArbeiten.pdf) pp.31-43 (in german)

Example:

Name, First name / Name, First name: „Article title. Subtitle“, in: Name, First name / Name, First name (Hrsg.), *Book title. Subtitle*, Publishing place(s): Publisher year, S. x-y.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Have you asked the support of overleaf?

Comment: Thank you, glad to be here! I haven't done that yet, I only tried to find something in the docs, but that's a good idea!

Comment: There's no need to use `biblatex.cfg` or `biblatex.def` to do what you want to do. The beauty of `biblatex` is almost everything you will need to do can be done within your document if needed. If you need to look at the source code for `biblatex` then you can find it on CTAN if really needed.

Comment: For example, your system looks basically like the standard `authortitle` style, with the following additions: `\renewcommand{\multinamedelim}{\addslash}\renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}{\addslash}\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}`. There may need to be some further modifications, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have direct access to the TeX system used by Overleaf, so accessing system files is not easy. But it should not be necessary in your case anyway.

The default `biblatex.cfg` is functionally empty. So you could just create a new empty file on Overleaf and use that.

But I wouldn't even do that. I disagree about `biblatex.cfg` with https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13076/35864 (and answer that I hold in very high regards). `biblatex.cfg` is supposed to be a global configuration file that is loaded by all documents loading `biblatex`. That means that it can be sort of "invisible" to you that the file is used and loaded until you check the `.log` file. This can lead to confusion and unexpected output.

There are many places where you can put your `biblatex` modifications ([Biblatex.cfg vs .cls vs .sty](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/296732/35864)), but unless they are really long I think the preamble is the best place: That way you always see your modifications right away so you can never be surprised by them.

Just from the example you gave in your question you might want to try something like

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ext-verbose-ibid, innamebeforetitle]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{ineditor}{sortname}

\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\addspace\slash\space}
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareDelimAlias{translatortypedelim}{editortypedelim}
\DeclareFieldAlias{translatortype}{editortype}


\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space}

\renewcommand*{\subtitlepunct}{\addperiod\space}


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
ipsum \autocite{sigfridsson}
dolor \autocite{pines}
sit \autocite{worman}
amet \autocite{pines}
consectur \autocite{nussbaum}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Pines, Shlomo: „The Limitations of Human Knowledge According to Al-Farabi, ibn Bajja, and Maimonides“, in: Twersky, Isadore (Hrsg.): Studies in Medieval Jewish History and Literature, Cambridge, Mass.: Harvard University Press, 1979, S. 82–109.]

Just for fun, here is a little trick to access system files on Overleaf. You use `cp` in a shell escape, to copy the file into the working directory so that it can be accessed via "Other logs and files" (cf. [Overleaf V2 - How to get BBL File?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/462314/35864)).

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\usepackage{shellesc}
\ShellEscape{%
  cp $(kpsewhich biblatex.def) .
}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: The "Other logs and files" menu with biblatex.def highlighted.]

Comment: Thanks! I added `\renewmacro*{publisher+location+date}` to get rid of the comma before the year - is their a simpler alternative? - and now it looks quite good!

Comment: I also need to change the position of series+number to be behind publisher+location+year. I tried ```\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\@for\next:=book,inbook,collection,incollection,proceedings,inproceedings\do{%
  \xpatchbibdriver{\next}{\usebibmacro{series+number}}{}{}{}%
  \xpatchbibdriver{\next}{\usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}}{\usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}\newunit\newblock\usebibmacro{series+number}}{}{}
}
\makeatother``` but sadly it isn't working. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @brathenne I suggest you ask new questions about the things you want to change. Ask one question per issue and include a working example document (with suitable `.bib` entry) that shows what you have at the moment.